# Does Hotspot shield hide internet activities from office firewall?

Tags: security, firewall, hotspot-shield

Our office's firewall is blocking many websites. i can access those block sites using Hotspot Shield but my question is that do my internet activities log into firewall log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works via VPN, so what they'll see is that you have a VPN connection to Hotspot Shield's servers, and the amount of traffic that passes through that connection. They won't be able to see what you're sending back and forth, though they'll be able to measure the amount of traffic.

Comment: You answered first... so marking yours... Josh is right too (but sorry Josh)

Comment: also anonymizing (sic) sites are quite often run by law enforcement agencies!  So don't think your getting away with anything!

Answer (score 0):

Because Hotspot is a VPN service it's all encrypted. They won't be able to see what you're sending.

VPN = "Virtual Private Network"

They will, however, be able to see that you're almost exclusively talking to one computer. This might arouses suspicion or lead to other, more intrusive methods of blocking (such as installing monitoring software on your computer).

Comment: you may be right.. It can arise other problems.....Thanks man

Comment: @learner: Best bet would be to bring your own computer. :) Though a VPN solution is very secure.